# *.bb file error: parser error when using if else condition in yocto sumo

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I want to use kernel 4.14 for target1 and kernel 4.9 for target2. And I have added the below code for the same and its working completely fine.

```
SRC_URI = "${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target1', 'file://kernel/k-4.14/net/kernel/', '', d)} \
           ${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target2', 'file://kernel/k-4.9/net/kernel/', '', d)}"

S = "${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target1', '${WORKDIR}/kernel/k-4.14/net/kernel/', '', d)} \
     ${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target2', '${WORKDIR}/kernel/k-4.9/net/kernel/', '', d)}"
```

But for all other targets if the path "kernel/k-3.18/net/kernel/" is present i want to use it. if not present throw error. And I am not able to add this condition to the bb file. I have used if else condition and tried, but I got parser error. Even I have tried to add the python code but it did not help. Below is the snippet which i tried.

```
    work_dir = d.getVar("WORKDIR", expand=True)
    KERNEL_3_18_PATH_FILE_CMD = ''
    KERNEL_3_18_PATH  = ''
    python do_package_prepend() {
        if os.path.exists(work_dir+/kernel/k-3.18/net/kernel/):
            KERNEL_3_18_PATH_FILE_CMD = "kernel/k-3.18/net/kernel/"
            KERNEL_3_18_PATH = work_dir + "/kernel/k-3.18/net/kernel/"
}
    SRC_URI = "${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target2', 'file://kernel/k-4.9/net/kernel/', 'file://KERNEL_3_18_PATH_FILE_CMD', d)}"

    S = "${@oe.utils.conditional('BASEMACHINE', 'target2', 'file://kernel/k-4.9/net/kernel/', 'KERNEL_3_18_PATH', d)}"
```

Can you please help. I am new to python and yocto

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution would be to set PREFERRED_VERSION for your kernel recipe per-machine.

For example, the oe-core BSPs do this:

```
meta-yocto-bsp/conf/machine/beaglebone-yocto.conf:
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto ?= "4.18%"
```